# how to retrieve a Double value from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-intent, casting, double

I have made an application containing 2 activities ,in that first activity contains some EditTexts (decimal numbers),and anothe ractivity also contains some Edtitexts(decimal) ,now I want to pass one EditText's value to another but as a "double" not as a string.Because that values will be used in mathematical calculation. I want that values in "double" strictly.
I have tried as below: but have no idea how to cast a String to "double".

**activity1.java**

```
    final Double d1;
        final Double d2;
        final Double d3;
        final Double d4;
        final Double d5;
        final Double d6;
        final Double d7;
        final Double d8;
        d1=Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
        d2=Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString());
        d3=Double.parseDouble(et3.getText().toString());
        d4=Double.parseDouble(et4.getText().toString());
        d5=Double.parseDouble(et5.getText().toString());
        d6=Double.parseDouble(et6.getText().toString());
        d7=Double.parseDouble(et7.getText().toString());
        d8=Double.parseDouble(et8.getText().toString());
.
.
.
.
Intent ic = new Intent(Calculator_1Activity.this,Calculator2a.class);
        ic.putExtra("doubleValue_e1", d1);
        ic.putExtra("doubleValue_e2", d2);
        ic.putExtra("doubleValue_e3", d3);
        ic.putExtra("doubleValue_e4", d4);
        ic.putExtra("doubleValue_e5", d5);
        ic.putExtra("doubleValue_e6", d6);
        ic.putExtra("doubleValue_e7", d7);
        ic.putExtra("doubleValue_e8", d8);

        startActivity(ic);
```

**Activity2.java**

```
Intent receiveIntent = this.getIntent();
        e1 = receiveIntent.getDoubleExtra("doubleValue_e1", 0.00);
        e2 = receiveIntent.getDoubleExtra("doubleValue_e2", 0.00);
        e3 = receiveIntent.getDoubleExtra("doubleValue_e3", 0.00);
        e4 = receiveIntent.getDoubleExtra("doubleValue_e4", 0.00);
        e5 = receiveIntent.getDoubleExtra("doubleValue_e5", 0.00);
        e6 = receiveIntent.getDoubleExtra("doubleValue_e6", 0.00);
        e7 = receiveIntent.getDoubleExtra("doubleValue_e7", 0.00);
        e8 = receiveIntent.getDoubleExtra("doubleValue_e8", 0.00);

        Calculator_1Activity cal1 = new Calculator_1Activity();
        et1.setText(cal1.et1.getText().toString());
```

i have tried this but still not working.my project stops unexpectly..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a double value through to a different class in Android Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588026/passing-a-double-value-through-to-a-different-class-in-android-java)

Answer (score 10):

**Sending Double From First Activity :**

```
Intent sendingIntent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("doubleValue_e1", doubleData);
intent.putExtra("doubleValue_e2", doubleData);
intent.putExtra("doubleValue_e3", doubleData);
intent.putExtra("doubleValue_e4", doubleData);
startActivity(sendingIntent);
```

**Receiving Double in Second Activity :**

```
double e1,e2,e3,e4;
Intent receiveIntent = this.getIntent();
e1 = intent.getDoubleExtra("doubleValue_e1", defaultValue)
e2 = intent.getDoubleExtra("doubleValue_e2", defaultValue)
e3 = intent.getDoubleExtra("doubleValue_e3", defaultValue)
e4 = intent.getDoubleExtra("doubleValue_e4", defaultValue)
```

Comment: My frend thank you,but can you please tell me how can i send multiple values from 1 activtiy to another activity?

Comment: put more extras with intent. You can send multiple values via an intent

Comment: Brothr-i have edited my code as per you suggestion,but not working my frend..i have edited my question too.please see it..and help if u can..thanking you brother.

Comment: Reason For converting String in to Double?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double.parseDouble(my_string);`

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

Double.parseDouble(String s) the use a Bundle to pass info from one activity to other.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your Double to String, put into bundle, and get parse back to string in another activity

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert your double `DATA` to a string using the `Double.toString()` method.
2. Send this string over the intent.

   ```
   intent.putExtra("DoubleWhichNowIsAString", DATA);
   ```
3. Get it back at receiver as

   ```
   getIntent().getStringExtra("DoubleWhichNowIsAString")
   ```
4. Parse back the string to a double using `Double.parseDouble()` function.